# i am getting Exception caught by widgets library

Tags: flutter, dart

```dart
import 'package:app1/answer.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'question.dart';
import 'answer.dart';
void main() => runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
 @override
 MyAppState createState() => MyAppState();
}
class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
 var questionindex = 0;
 void answerquestion() {
   if (questionindex == 1) questionindex = -1;
   setState(() {
     questionindex++;
   });
   print(questionindex);
   print("answer chosen");
 }

 final List<Map<String, Object>> question = [
   {
     'questionText': 'what is your fav color?',
     'answers': ['black', 'green', 'blue', 'yellow']
   },
   {
     'questionText': 'whats your fav animal?',
     'answers': ['rabbit', 'dog', 'cat', 'monkey']
   },
 ];

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     theme: ThemeData(
         elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
             style: ButtonStyle(
       backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
     ))),
     home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBar(
         title: Text("quiz app"),
       ),
       body: Container(
         child: Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             Question(question[questionindex]['questionText'] as String),
             ...(question[questionindex]['answers'] as List<String>).map(
               (answer1) {
                 return Answer(answerquestion, answer1);
               },
             ).toList(),
           ],
         ),
       ),
     ),
   );
 }
}
```

these are the exception that i am getting

```
═════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
A RenderFlex overflowed by 399452 pixels on the bottom.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Column

Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Answer
```

Answer (score 0):

Add Your Column Widget **SingleChildScrollView** or **Expanded** insted of **Container**

```
SingleChildScrollView(
child:Column(
           children: <Widget>[
             Question(question[questionindex]['questionText'] as String),
             ...(question[questionindex]['answers'] as List<String>).map(
               (answer1) {
                 return Answer(answerquestion, answer1);
               },
             ).toList(),
           ],
         ),
),
```

Comment: it didn't work i still got the same error with the SingleChildScrollView  and with the expanded

Comment: Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Answer
lib\main.dart:54
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by rendering library ═════════════════════════════════
Every child of a RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox must have an ID in its parent data.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Scaffold
lib\main.dart:44

Comment: that is the answer file if it helps `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Answer extends StatelessWidget {
  late String answertext;
  late Function x;
  Answer(this.x, this.answertext);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: x(),
        child: Text(answertext),
      ),
    );
  }
}
`

Answer (score 0):

Design your widget tree like like this and let me know if the error persists or not :

```
  @override
     Widget build(BuildContext context) {
       return MaterialApp(
         theme: ThemeData(
             elevatedButtonTheme: ElevatedButtonThemeData(
                 style: ButtonStyle(
           backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
         ))),
         home: SafeArea(
    child: Scaffold(
           appBar: AppBar(
             title: Text("quiz app"),
           ),
           body: Container(
    child:SingleChildScrollView(
             child: Column(
               children: <Widget>[
                 Question(question[questionindex]['questionText'] as String),
                 ...(question[questionindex]['answers'] as List<String>).map(
                   (answer1) {
                     return Answer(answerquestion, answer1);
                   },
                 ).toList(),
               ],
             ),
           ),//SingleChildScrollView
         ),//Container
       ),//Scaffold
         ),//SafeArea
); //MaterialApp
     }
    }
```

Comment: the column exception stopped showing but the answer one kept showing 
════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
The relevant error-causing widget was
Answer
lib\main.dart:56

Comment: this is the answer file: ``` import 'package:flutter/material.dart';  class Answer extends StatelessWidget {   late String answertext;   late Function x;   Answer(this.x, this.answertext);   @override   Widget build(BuildContext context) {     return Container(       width: double.infinity,       child: ElevatedButton(         onPressed: x(),         child: Text(answertext),       ),     );   } } ```